# a problem involving geometric sequence

Tags: contest-math, geometric-series

The question I am asking is this

> Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers such that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $a$, $b + 1$, $c + 2$ are both geometric sequences in their respective orders. Compute the smallest possible value of $(a + b + c)^2$.

This problem is related to a question in an AMC competition. I have nowhere to start except $xa=b$, $xb= c$, and $ya=b+1$, $y(b+1)=c+2$.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $a c = b^2$ and $a (c+2) = (b+1)^2$. Compute $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$.